# Deleteing Apex trigger

Tags: community, sandbox

I deployed an Apex trigger to production.
Now I want to delete it - how can i do it?
I tried turning it to inacive and uploading the outbound change set but it doesn't work.
Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to delete a Trigger or Apex Class or VF Page from Production is by using ANT Scripts. Create destructiveChanges.xml and deploy destructive changes to Production.

Check this link on how to create destructiveChanges.xml
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes

NOTE: Make sure that the Trigger which you are trying to delete has no dependencies with other files. I would recommend deleting it in Sandbox first before trying it in production.